# Unresolved reference: sourceSets for Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Trying to migrate my existing `build.gradle` to Kotlin and I am getting the following error in my project:

```
Script compilation error:

  Line 86:         from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
                        ^ Unresolved reference: sourceSets

1 error
```

The error is coming from my `subprojects` block when I try to define the `sourcesJar` task:

```
subprojects {
    val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
        classifier = "sources"
        from(sourceSets["main"].allSource) // error here
    }

    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        publications {
            register("mavenJava", MavenPublication::class) {
                from(components["java"])
                artifact(sourcesJar.get())
            }
        }
    }

    val implementation by configurations
    val compileOnly by configurations
    val annotationProcessor by configurations

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure")
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm using the following:

- Gradle 4.10.2
- Kotlin 1.2.70

Beginning part of the `build.gradle.kts` before `subprojects` block:

```
import com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.KotlinExtension
import com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.SpotlessExtension
import io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.dsl.DependencyManagementExtension
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val kotlinVersion: String by extra
val springBootVersion: String by extra

buildscript {
    val kotlinVersion: String by extra { "1.2.70" }
    val springBootVersion: String by extra { "2.0.6.RELEASE" }
    repositories {
        maven {
            val nexusPublicRepoURL: String by project
            url = uri(nexusPublicRepoURL)
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath("com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:3.9.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.2.70")
    }
}

allprojects {
    val projectGroup: String by project
    group = projectGroup

    apply(plugin = "kotlin")
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin-spring")
    apply(plugin = "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")

    configure<DependencyManagementExtension> {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion")
            mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.SR1")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            val nexusPublicRepoURL: String by project
            url  = uri(nexusPublicRepoURL)
        }
    }

    tasks.existing(KotlinCompile::class) {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }

    configure<SpotlessExtension> {
        kotlin {
            ktlint()
        }
    }

    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        repositories {
            maven {
                val nexusReleaseRepoURL: String by project
                val nexusSnapshotRepoURL: String by project
                val nexusUsername: String by project
                val nexusPassword: String by project
                val version = if ((project.version as String).contains("SNAPSHOT")) nexusReleaseRepoURL else nexusSnapshotRepoURL
                url = uri(version)
                credentials {
                    username = nexusUsername
                    password = nexusPassword
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, you should be able to use `the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"]`

Comment: @JBNizet doing that produces a new error `Extension of type 'SourceSetContainer' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension]
`

Comment: Have you applied a plugin on each of your subprojects that actually adds sourceSets to the project (like the java plugin, for example)

Comment: I've applied the `java-library` plugin in the `allprojects` block. See my edit that shows the rest of my `build.gradle.kts`.

Comment: Sorry: simple scoping issue. `the()` is resolved to `this.the()`, i.e. `Task::the()`. Change it to `project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"]`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Please post as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the plugin is applied imperatively in the same build script, Gradle can't know the plugin is applied and thus can't generate the extension functions allowing to access the source sets.

So you need to get the source set programmatically:

```
project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"]
```

Don't use

```
the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"]
```

otherwise the `the()` function will be resolved on the current task being configured instead of the project.

Comment: Just to be clear. Should I replace the `from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)` with `from(project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"])` ?

Comment: No. You should replace sourceSets["main"] by the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"]

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Funny the GitHub examples don't mention it. https://github.com/gradle-guides/building-kotlin-jvm-libraries/blob/master/samples/code/my-kotlin-library/build.gradle.kts#L51

Comment: But what to do with the line `sourcesJar.get()`?

Comment: Still failling for me :(
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62982138/1423773