# Unresolved reference: sourceSets - Gradle Kotlin DSL in another file

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, source-sets

In Gradle (Groovy), I used to do this to configure source sets:

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'gradle/test.gradle'
```

`gradle/test.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        compileClasspath += main.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output
    }
}
```

And then I'd use the `unitTest` source set for creating tasks.

When I try to do the same in IntelliJ for Gradle KTS:

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    java
}

apply(from = "gradle/test.gradle.kts")
```

`gradle/test.gradle.kts`:

```
sourceSets {
    create("unitTest") {
     // Do configurations
    }
}
```

If fails with a `Unresolved reference: sourceSets` error.

How can I this same thing in Kotlin Gradle?

Comment: It does find the file. The Unresolved Reference is when it's trying to "compile" `gradle/test.gradle`. This exact code in Groovy works.

Comment: If I try to rename the file, the error is different (file not found of some sort)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved reference: sourceSets for Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975515/unresolved-reference-sourcesets-for-gradle-kotlin-dsl)

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of duplication of [Unresolved reference: sourceSets for Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975515/unresolved-reference-sourcesets-for-gradle-kotlin-dsl)

You can't reference sourceSet directly when using separate gradle file.
From referenced answer:

> Since the plugin is applied imperatively in the same build script,
> Gradle can't know the plugin is applied and thus can't generate the
> extension functions allowing to access the source sets.

As mentioned, you can use `project.the<SourceSetContainer>()`

To create new sourceSet `create()` method can be used.

`project.the<SourceSetContainer>().create("unitTest")`