# SoftwareComponentInternal with name 'java' not found

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, bintray

App module `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: rootProject.file('deploy-bintray.gradle.kts')
android {...}
```

**deploy-bintray.gradle.kts** it's my bintray/maven publications script.

I'm having problems generating .jar files:

```
val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"].allSource)
}

publications {
        create<MavenPublication>(bintrayRepo) {
            groupId = publishedGroupId
            artifactId = artifact
            version = libraryVersion

            from(components["java"])
            artifact(sourcesJar.get())
            artifact(dokkaJar.get())
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

it fails with:

> SoftwareComponentInternal with name 'java' not found.

or, if I comment `from(components["java"])` it fails with:

> SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

If I add java plugin:

> The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the
> Android plugins.

So I'm stuck here.  How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm stuck with this too.

Comment: Can't find help about this anywhere...

Comment: @Mr.Moustard I've found a solution

Comment: I’ll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found a solution!
I was doing a few things wrong, first, both *dokkaJar* and *sourceJar* tasks have to be in the main `build.gradle` and not inside `deploy-bintray.gradle.kts`. Moving them made it work and fixes:

> `SourceSet with name 'main' not found.`

Secondly we cannot use `from(components["java"])` because this is an Android lib so I've replaced that line with `artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar")`.

Last but not least, as stated [here (step 7)](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin):

> "Also, the POM file generated does not include the dependency chain so
> it must be explicitly added..."

I had to add this:

```
pom {
...
    withXml {
       val dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
       configurations.getByName("implementation") {
         dependencies.forEach {
            val dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency")
            dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
            dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
            dependencyNode.appendNode("version", it.version)
         }
       }     
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use from(components["java"]), right code like this:

```
create<MavenPublication>("ReleaseAar") {
    groupId = "com.example"
    artifactId = "lib-git-repository"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    afterEvaluate { artifact(tasks.getByName("bundleReleaseAar")) 
}
```